# django rest return result that combines filters

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django rest and i'm trying to return response that have to use two query sets:
The first one is for the specific project and the second one is only for specific users inside this project:

serializers.py

```
class ProjectFiltersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Project
        fields = ('id', 'title','users')
```

views.py

```
class FiltersDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve filters instance.
    """
    def get_project(self, project_pk):
        try:
            return models.Project.objects.filter(pk=project_pk)
        except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get_returning_customers(self, project_pk):
        return [(u.pk, u"%s %s" % (u.first_name, u.last_name)) for u in User.objects.filter(return=1)]

    def get(self, request, project_pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_project(project_pk) | self.get_returning_customers(project_pk)
        serializer = ProjectFiltersSerializer(snippet, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I'm getting "Cannot combine queries on two different base models".
Is this the right way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: can you please format your code

Comment: It look like you are trying to combine two query with `|` that don't return the same type. One retuns `User` and the other `Project` instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nested Serializer. For more information: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: But then they must have some relationship between them. what if I want to add model that doesn't has one?

Comment: @OS This seems like you're trying to return related users. If the objects aren't related in any way, there wouldn't be a reason to return it with a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

create a nested serializer (notice it's not a Model Serializer)

```
class ProjectCustomerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    users = UserSerializer(many=True)
    project = ProjectSerializer()
```

the UserSerializer and ProjectSerializer can be ModelSerializers however. Then in the view:

```
def get(....):
   serializer = ProjectCustomerSerializer(data={
    'users': self.get_returning_customers(project_pk),
    'project': self.get_project(project_pk),
   })
   return Response(serializer.data)
```

there's another way. You could add a method on the project model (get_returning_customers()) and then add a field on the ProjectSerializer called `returning_customers = serializer.ListField(source='get_returning_customers')`

Hope this helps